# Isuue with ToC linking sections

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, hyperlink

I have a code with multiple parts and each part has multiple sections and subsections, but I want to reset the counter of sections so it start again in each part using `\setcounter{section}{0}`; which causes linking sections to the wrong ones, for example if I have:

Part 1:
Section 1
Section 2

Part 2:
Section 1

Then clicking Part 2-Section 1 will transfer to Part 1-Section 1.

Is there a way to reset counter without causing this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black,}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\part{Part Test 1}

\section{Test Sec1}

\subsection{Test sub}

\section{Test Sec2}

\subsection{Test Sub2}

\newpage
\setcounter{section}{0}
\part{Part Test 1}

\section{Test Sec1}

\subsection{Test sub}

\section{Test Sec2}

\subsection{Test Sub2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` requires targets to be unique. When you reset the section counter like this then they are no longer unique. An extra measure need to be taken. Details depend (a little) on your setup

Comment: use `\counterwithin{section}{part}` to reset the counters automatically (after loading hyperref), then hyperref should take care of it.

Comment: Thank you both Daleif and Ulrike! Using `\counterwithin{section}{part}` solves the issue!